# how to print a tuble within list from data collected from a file

Tags: python, list, tuples

Say the file contains the following:

```
Quizzes Assignments Projects Midterms Final

0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.4
```

How do I get the output to look like the following:

```
[('Quizzes', 0.1), ('Assignments', 0.1), ('Projects', 0.2), ('Midterms', 0.2), ('Final', 0.4)]
```

this is my code now:

```
def grade_parts(data_list):
    new_list = []
    for lists in data_list:
        new_list.append(tuple(lists[0].strip().split()))
    return new_list
```

Comment: What kind of file? What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: i promt the user for a file and he inserts a file that contains Quizzes Assignments Projects Midterms Final

0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.4

Comment: using a for loop im trying to combine quizzes with 0,1 and assignments with 0,1 and etc

Comment: what have you tried? do you have an error?  something that could help is to use `.split`. for example, `"my string".split(" ")` which splits on the space to form, `["my", "string"]`

Comment: my current output is: [('Quizzes',), ('0.1',)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip`:

```
line1 = "Quizzes Assignments Projects Midterms Final"
line2 = "0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.4"
list(zip(line1.split(' '),line2.split(' ')))

##EDIT: a variation with a list of list
[(val,line2.split(' ')[idx]) for idx, val in enumerate(line1.split(' ')) ]
```

**Output**

```
[('Quizzes', '0.1'),
 ('Assignments', '0.1'),
 ('Projects', '0.2'),
 ('Midterms', '0.2'),
 ('Final', '0.4')]
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without zip, and using for loop

Comment: just posted it!